# svg file display

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Svg support on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889882/svg-support-on-android)

i want a sample program for displaying svg file in android? or i want to know wha are the classes used for it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native SVG support in Android, you could use [SVG4Mobile](http://code.google.com/p/svg4mobile/) but it is GPL licensed rather than LGPL.

I have written a very lightweight, pure Android SVG renderer myself and plan to release it under a permissive Apache/BSD style license, but it is incomplete and will never support the full SVG spec.

I will release the source code over the next day or so [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-svg/), but beware that this is an early alpha!