# Using an SVG as a background drawable in Android

Tags: android, background, svg

I'm trying to use an SVG image (created using Inkscape and saved as plain SVG) as a background for my application. I'm trying to do this using the `svg-android` library. I have a file called `background.svg` in `res/raw`. My code looks like this:

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.background);
Drawable pictureDrawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

LinearLayout backgroundLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
backgroundLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

However when my application starts up, nothing shows up as the background (other than the background color from the layout). My layout xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#aacceeff"
    >

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    >
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

It appears that there is a problem with my SVG. It might be due to the fact that all features are not supported.

Comment: Have you tried to set the Drawable pictureDrawable as a background of the layout instead of BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable?

Comment: @DimitrisMakris Yes, that was the first thing I tried but I still got a blank background. Another problem is that there is no way to set the tiling on a `PictureDrawable`.

Comment: Just in case;-
U know android does not natively support SVG
Try your code on firefox for Android?

Comment: Yes, not natively, but the svg-android library helps you work with SVG's on android.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The svg-android project hasn't been updated in over a year and it doesn't support SVG1.2 so svgs generated by Inkscape (open-source) aren't supported.

There is however a new android svg library: [AndroidSVG](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/)

They are on version 1.2 and work on 1.3 is currently in progress. Including just the jar library one can programatically include svgs in android applications. Almost all svg features are included. I am yet to find an svg that I was unable to incorporate using this library.

If you include androidsvg from source (hg clone) in your project as a library module you get the SVGImageView class which is an extension of ImageView whereby you can add svg to your project using the xml layout files like so:

```
<com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView
    xmlns:svg="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    svg:svg="filename.svg"/>
```

That's it. All you need to to do is place `filename.svg` in the assets folder and you are good to go.

It supports API 8 and above. There were a few issues when using it for API < 11 but I was able to fix these. I posted them as issues on the project page and the authors responded within minutes. They have been added to the next revision. If you have any problems look at the resolved issues, failing which I am available to answer questions here.

P.S. The documentation and examples on the project page are excellent and the library is a joy to work with. Android and svg are a powerful mix.

Answer (score 1):

I tried an example using the following code and it is shows the background correctly:

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),
                R.raw.android_body);
Drawable pictureDrawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
root.setBackgroundDrawable(pictureDrawable);
```

Have you tried with another svg?

Comment: I did try loading up the SVG in a browser and it seems to show up fine so it doesn't look like there's anything wrong with it. Let me try another svg. Oh, also did you try it with the nested layouts like the way I have it? I wonder if that is contributing to the problem.

Comment: Yeap, exaclty the same layout, but yep this is irrelevant. The svg i use is from the svg-android project (the live wallpaper project)

Comment: I tried it with the svg they provided and it seems to work. So I guess it's an issue with my svg.