# Can we use svg images in android ? If we can use then how to use them in android

Tags: android, svg

In my android app, I have a thought of using svg images instead of using different resolution images. I tried to use svg-android jar which is available in git which is used to parse the svg images. But when I am using this jar I'm getting parsing error.
Even this method of using svg images is not flexible, because we need to parse every image that we are going to use in app.
So please help me in this regard, and also let me know if there is any other way to use svg images in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19742892/4596556

Comment: Yes, we can, if we use a 3rd party (free) library, such as [android-svg](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg) - to name one.

Answer (score 1):

Android now officially supports svg. For details check this out
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/09/android-studio-14.html