# How to show svg image in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to show svg image file format image in android device? How it is possible. Also I want .svg image samples for download. Also I want to know, Is there any website, that satisfy my question of answer.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889882/svg-support-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the below shown link ,And read it carefully.. You will get the idea to solve :

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/10/displaying-svg-images-in-android/